# I don't know how to through one queryset type to manytomany relations

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I want to use Django to write a blog system.But the question is I can't get tags queryset from articles queryset.

models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,related_name='tags')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field="username",
    )
    ...

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='username',)
    ...
```

views:

```
....
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    user=self.request.user
    object_list=Article.objects.all().filter(author=self.request.user.username).order_by(F('created').desc())[:100]
    kwargs['tags']=??? # I want to get a tags queryset related to object_list
    return super(UserIndexView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: You want to get all tags for all articles in `object_list`?

Comment: Yeah. Is that be OK??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `related_name` wrong. `related_name` is the name for the reversed relationship. It should be:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,related_name='articles')
```

So the simple answer to your question is use:

```
[article.tags.all() for article in object_list]
```

But this is not efficient since it issues 100 separate queries to the DB.
A better way to do this would be:

```
Tags.objects.filter(articles__author=self.request.user.username)
```

(Note the use of the `related_name` property)

But I've omitted the interesting part of only getting tags related to the 100 newest articles of the user. To do this, I think the best way is to first get the date of the 100th article, and then filter accordingly:

```
ordered_articles = Article.objects.filter(author=self.request.user.username).order_by(F('created').desc()
try:
    date_limit = ordered_articles[100].created
    return Tags.objects.filter(articles__author=self.request.user.username, articles__created__lt=date_limit)
except IndexError:
    return Tags.objects.filter(articles__author=self.request.user.username)
```

(Answer not tested, sorry)

Also, call your model `Tag` instead of `Tags`.